# Trim all extra spaces in string for an Access column

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

[SOLVED] I played around with my Update query this is what ended up working

```
UPDATE NewData SET NewData.[Vendor Name1] = 
Trim(replace(replace(Replace([Vendor Name1],' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' '));
```

I have created an Update query to select an entire column in which I have to trim. However, I learned that Access's trim is different than Excel's trim. 
I want to be able to remove all extra spaces before and after the string, but also any extra spaces in between.

For example "__X_X__XXX____X_X_" turns into "A_A_AAA_A_A"

Is there a VBA function or UPDATE SQL code that can help me achieve this?
The fieldname is [Vendor Name1] (not the best column name, but it is what is being used at the moment)

Other information that I think will help, the column is being pulled and updated from a querytable [NewData]

Comment: You could repeatedly run an UPDATE query that will REPLACE([Vendor Name1], "_X", "X")

Comment: The point is to not have to repeat running the query.

Comment: Add your solution below as its own answer!

Comment: Remember Access and Excel are very different softwares not to be confused or conflated. Likely, Access' `TRIM` follows the [SQL standard](https://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) to only remove leading and trailing spaces